# Risk about world writable file

Tags: linux, permissions

I need some help about permissions on Linux. I know having world writable file can be dangerous and many people recommend to not have world writable file.

In order to "protect" my Linux, i searched for every world writable file using `find / -perm -0002 -type f`. Thanks to this command, I found a world writable file under my `/root/a_directory/`. As my `/root` directory is `700`, other user cant edit the world writable file.

So my question is, what is the risk if I have world writable file under a directory which can't be access by other users ?

Am i safe if `/directory1/world_writable_file.sh` is `777` and `/directory1/` is `700`. Is there no risk with this situation ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Directory permissions behave quite differently from file permissions.

Since the directory doesn't allow other (non-root and non-group) users any operation (read/write/execute) on the directory, they can't even enumerate the files inside this directory, so they sure can't access them.

Here is a practical example:

```
user@host$ sudo su
root@host$ mkdir testdir
root@host$ printf '#!/bin/bash\necho test" > testdir/testfile
root@host$ chmod 0777 testdir/testfile
root@host$ chmod 0700 testdir
root@host$ exit
user@host$ ./testdir/testfile
-bash: ./testdir/testfile: Permission denied
user@host$ ls testdir
ls: cannot open directory 'testdir': Permission denied
```

However, this is NOT a good practice in handling sensitive files.
It is very easy to misconfigure file permissions, so you should never rely on having a secure directory.

If someone accidentally changes the directory's permission to 0701 (others can execute), which seems like a fairly negligible change, everyone will be able to execute, read and write any file with `0777` permissions if they know its exact path.

Moreover, the scenario you described can happen only if:

A. The permissions on the directory are changed after the files are already there. In this case, you should simply use `chmod -R o-rwx` to remove permissions for other users.

B. The directory owner created the file after the directory was already configured, and then added permissions using `chmod o+wx` or something similar. Since new files created in a directory with `0700` permissions mask, have a default mask of `0644`, and the only user that can access the directory is the owner, there is no other way. In this case, simply refrain from doing so.

---

Anyway, if you are interested in reading and understanding more about UIDs in Unix systems in general and Linux in specific, [I wrote a comprehensive guide on the subject](https://medium.com/@dtrugman/unraveling-the-unix-uid-conundrum-fbd5b13004fd).